# Android volley incorrect work on mobile internet

Tags: android, android-volley

I have some problems with sending headers in volley when i use mobile internet. I sending two headers: `Cookie` and `If-Modified-Since`. `Cookie` is correctly sending on server but `If-Modified-Since` doesn't come to the server. If i change header name to `IfModifiedSince` or to ever another name, it comes. On the WiFi connection all works perfectly.
This is my request:

```
Request request;

 request = new Request(Request.Method.GET,      Addresses.new_count,
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        if (error.toString().contains("TimeoutError") || // "com.android.volley.TimeoutError".equals(error.toString())
                                "com.android.volley.TimeoutError.NoConnectionError".equals(error.toString())) { //.contains("com.android.volley.TimeoutError.NoConnectionError")) {
                            String dd = "";
                            // Обработка ошибки
                        } else if ("com.android.volley.AuthFailureError".equals(error.toString()) ||
                                error.toString().contains("No authentication") || error.toString().contains("Received authentication challenge is null")) {
                            // not autorithation 401
                            Preferences.get().eraseCookie();
                            Preferences.get().eraseTocken();
                            Preferences.get().eraseOther();
                            Preferences.get().eraseRegistration();
                            Intent intent = new Intent(context, Start.class);
                            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                            context.startActivity(intent);
                            finish();
                        } else {
                            getNew();
                        }

                    }
                }) {
            @Override
            protected Response parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
                int code = response.statusCode;
                if (code == 200) {
                    String str = new String(response.data);
                    if (!"[]".equals(str))
                        try {
                            DatabaseHelper.putToDb(getApplicationContext(), str);
                        } catch (JsonSyntaxException e) {
                            Connection.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).cancelPendingRequests(MainActivity.class.getName());
                            Preferences.get().eraseCookie();
                            Preferences.get().eraseTocken();
                            Preferences.get().eraseOther();
                            Preferences.get().eraseRegistration();
                            Intent intent = new Intent(context, Start.class);
                            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                            context.startActivity(intent);
                            Preferences.get().eraseCookie();
                            finish();
                        }
                    long tsLong = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000;
                    Preferences.get().putLong(Preferences.LAST_REQUEST, tsLong);
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            getSupportLoaderManager().getLoader(LoadType.MAINACTIVITY).forceLoad();
                            TimeTableFragment.refreshAdapter();
                        }
                    });
                }
                Preferences.get().checkSessionCookie(response.headers);
                Preferences.get().saveIMS(response.headers);
                return Response.success(response, null);
            }

            @Override
            protected void deliverResponse(Object response) {

            }

            @Override
            public int compareTo(Object o) {
                return 0;
            }

            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> headers = super.getHeaders();

                if (headers == null
                        || headers.equals(Collections.emptyMap())) {
                    headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
                }

                Preferences.get().addSessionCookie(headers);
                String curr_time_str = Preferences.get().getString(Preferences.IF_MODIFIED_SINCE);
                //if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(curr_time_str))
                    headers.put("If-Modified-Since", "Tue, 10 Dec 2015 10:10:23 GMT"); //"Tue, 11 Dec 2012 10:10:23 GMT"
                return headers;
            }
        };
    request.setShouldCache(false);
        Connection.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).addToRequestQueue(request, MainActivity.class.getName());
```

and my request queue init:

```
if (mRequestQueue == null) {
mRequestQueue = new RequestQueue(new NoCache(), new   BasicNetwork(new HurlStack())); //, httpStack
        mRequestQueue.start();
    }
```